# Referring to columns and variables with the same name in dplyr filter

Tags: r, dplyr

given this situation

```
id = "a"

df <- tibble(
  id = c("a", "b", "c"),
  value = c(1, 2, 3)
)

df %>% dplyr::filter(id == id)
```

I expected the last line to have the same output as `df %>% dplyr::filter(id == "a")` but it still refers to `id` as a df column and not as a variable. Can I enforce it to look for the variable `id`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could be achieved via the `.env` pronoun from `rlang`:

See e.g. this [blog post](https://tinyheero.github.io/2020/03/01/use-data-env-pronouns-tidyverse.html).

```r
library(dplyr)

id = "a"

df <- tibble(
  id = c("a", "b", "c"),
  value = c(1, 2, 3)
)

df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(id == .env$id)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   id    value
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1
```

Comment: What about if `id` is a variable of a function? Ok, it does work