# dplyr ambiguity with external vector when column on LHS

Tags: r, dplyr, ambiguity

Suppose I have:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(a=c(1,0,0),b=c(0,1,0),colname=c(0,0,1))
colname <- "a"
```

If I do

```
df %>% dplyr::select(colname)
```

The column takes precedence, and it returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 1
  colname
    <dbl>
1       0
2       0
3       1
```

If I want to evaluate the env-variable `colname`, I have to use `all_of`:

```
> df %>% dplyr::select(all_of(colname))
# A tibble: 3 × 1
      a
  <dbl>
1     1
2     0
3     0
```

I don't understand how to resolve the ambiguity in case the column is on LHS thought.
Suppose I want to change all `0` values of the column in the env-variable `colname` to `NA`:

```
df %>% dplyr::mutate(colname=replace(colname, colname==0, NA))
```

But this will change the third column (`colname`), not the first name (`a`).

Comment: Use the `.data` and `.env` pronouns to be more explicit. See https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/dot-data.html. Or in this case it would probably be easier to use `across`: `df %>% dplyr::mutate(across(all_of(colname), ~replace(.x, .x==0, NA)))`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70355426/referring-to-columns-and-variables-with-the-same-name-in-dplyr-filter/70355464#70355464

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe the `dplyr::mutate()` function needs to know whether `colname` refers to the existing column named 'colname' in the dataframe, or if it's referring to the variable in the environment.

In your current code, `dplyr::mutate()` interprets `colname` as the literal column name in the dataframe and therefore, it's replacing values in the `colname` column.

You can use the `across()` function together with `mutate()` to specify which columns you want to operate on as @MrFlick mentioned:

```
df <- tibble::tibble(a=c(1,0,0),b=c(0,1,0),colname=c(0,0,1))
colname <- "a"

df %>% mutate(across(all_of(colname), ~replace(., . == 0, NA)))
```

In this code, `across()` applies the `~replace(., . == 0, NA)` function across the column specified in `all_of(colname)`. The `~replace(., . == 0, NA)` function is a shorthand for defining a new function that replaces 0 values with NA.

The result of this operation would be:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a     b colname
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     0       0
2    NA     1       0
3    NA     0       1
```